# How to stop compilation process after the flattening step with the Open Modelica Compiler?

Tags: modelica, compiler-flags

I would like to have a look to the flattened version of a Modelica model. What's the right flag to pass to a Modelica compiler? Is that flag the same for the OpenModelica, JModelica or Dymola compiler?

Comment: The compilers are different, they don't support the same flags.
If you are in OMEdit, just right click the model on the right side and say Instantiate Model. You can also use from a .mos script instantiateModel(ModelPath).

Answer (score 3):

If you are in OMEdit, just right click the model on the right side and say Instantiate Model.

[image: OMEdit - Right Click -> Instantiate Model]

Comment: Maybe a flag to save the instantiated model to a text file would be a nice enhancement. Or, a save button from the popup window.

Comment: We already have a ticket for this enhancement, we'll implement it: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5751

Comment: Thank you Adrian for your fast and useful answer. I couldn't figure out what the button was for. I actually could use it to solve my immediate problems. However, that was not what I meant with the post. I was expecting something like the `-E`, `-c`, or `-S` options of the gcc compiler.

Comment: From the OpenModelica [online guide](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omchelptext.html#omcflag-debug), I found that the compiler should support an option `+d=nfDumpFlat`, which i thought could do the job, but in fact my version of the compiler, which is very recent, 1.14.1, does not recognise it (nor it is listed in the command line help). Like matth, I think that a command line option that leaves ther a file <filename>.mo.flat could be handy for people learning the language and/or having to debug a problem.